# Ajax request to C# function

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make an AJAX call to a function in my controller. I get an 404 response from this. What am I missing?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#anmal").on('click', function() {
    var fornamn = $('#fornamn input').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var efternamn = $('#efternamn input').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var forvaltning = $('#forvaltning input').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var arbetsplats = $('#arbetsplats input').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var mail = $('#mail input').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var mobilnummer = $('#arbetsplats input').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var hemadress = $('#hemadress input').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var ovrigt = $('#ovrigt ').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');

    if (fornamn != null && fornamn != '') {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/handler=AnmalDeltagare",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        data: {
          "fornamn": fornamn,
          "efternamn": efternamn,
          "forvaltning": forvaltning,
          "arbetsplats": arbetsplats,
          "mail": mail,
          "mobilnummer": mobilnummer,
          "hemadress": hemadress,
          "ovrigt:": ovrigt
        },
        dataType: "json"
      }).done(function(data) {
        if (data != 0) {
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the function in my `HomeController`. I also tried adding this to a model but no luck. It gives me the same 404 response.

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<ActionResult> onPostAnmalDeltagare(string fornmamn, string efternamn, string forvaltning, string arbetsplats, string mail, int mobilnummer, string hemadress, string ovrigt)
{
  return null;
}
```

Comment: please show your controller in more detail especially around the routing

Comment: Your route is wrong, you can't access controllers by default with the notation `/Home/handler=AnmalDeltagare`. Refer to your RouteConfig for the correct route. If it's the default asp.net mvc route, then it should be `/Home/onPostAnmalDeltagare`

Comment: whats is this hander in the url: "/Home/handler=AnmalDeltagare", ?

Comment: You should probably be using something like `url: '@Url.Action("AnmalDeltagare", "Home")',`

Comment: The name of your action needs to match your URL for routing purposes to reach the action you listed `/Home/onPostAnmalDeltagare`, unless you have customized your routing tables.

Answer (score 2):

An 404 response pretty much *always* means you have just typed the wrong URL. Yours looks suspicious:

```
/Home/handler=AnmalDeltagare
```

URL's just generally do not look like that. I suspect the correct URL should be

```
/Home/AnmalDeltagare
```

or perhaps

```
/Home/onPostAnmalDeltagare
```

But It could depend on how you have set up routing to your controllers.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but the URL would be `/Home/onPostAnmalDeltagare`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thats what I had originally, and got swayed by comments removing the `onPost` part - which I thought was some routing convention I was unaware of

Comment: It's certainly possible to do that, but it's not the default routing system - and this looks like a pretty vanilla instance of MVC.

Comment: Or even better. Seeing as they are using asp.net-mvc. Make use of the helper functions and use `@Url.Action("//method", "Home")`